# copy file from docker to host system using python script

Tags: python, docker

I have logged into the docker from the below command, now from the python script i want to copy the file  from docker to host system how to do this

```
      sudo  docker run -ti video:new /bin/bash

     import os
     os.system('cp /tmp/a.txt HOST:/tmp/a.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Map a volume** to share data with your host from the container.

```
docker run -v /tmp/:/tmp/ -ti video:new /bin/bash
```

Then let your python script copy the file to the `/tmp` directory *inside your container*.

```
 import os
 os.system('cp /path/to/a.txt /tmp/a.txt')
```

Through to the `-v` mapping, the file is placed on the docker host in the directory `/tmp`. Once you close your docker container, the file will still exist on the host as `/tmp/a.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The container can't copy information outside its isolation. If you wanna share information between container and host, please use volume mapper to do that (-v):

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/